# API.AI removes dots from parameters

Tags: dialogflow-es

as title says, api.ai removes dots from parameters.

For example if I write "bla bla bla google.com" where "google.com" is mapped to a parameter, the value of that parameter is "google com" and I don't find how to solve this problem. I also wrote to the api.ai team without an answer for now.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, thanks to api.ai team.

> Special symbols such as dots are removed from the resolved value.
>
> To obtain value with dot you can:
>
> - use @sys.url for URL inputs in this case "google.com" will be returned with dot
> - create additional parameter and set $parameterName.original -> for this parameter you will get exact phrase entered by user including
>     dots and other special symbols.

You can find the documentation about this here https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-actions#section-extracting-original-value

In my case:

[image]

I mark this answer for other people with same problem.